# Why does STD.FILE.LogicalFileList() results not completely correlate with STD.FILE.GetLogicalFileAttribute(x,y)?

Tags: dfu, dali, hpcc-ecl

I execute the statement:

```
NrmFiles     := NOTHOR(STD.File.LogicalFileList());
```

This produces a dataset of all the normal files contained in my HPCC environment.
It has the record layout:

```
    string lib_fileservices__fslogicalfilename := string{maxlength(255)};

    record__0 := RECORD
       lib_fileservices__fslogicalfilename name;
    END;
    FsLogicalFileInfoRecord := RECORD(record__0)
      boolean  superfile;
      integer8 size;
      integer8 rowcount;
      string19 modified;
      string   owner{maxlength(255)};
      string   cluster{maxlength(255)};
    END;
```

For my purpose, I need the workunit that created/modified each file, so I PROJECT that file
which produces a dataset of all the normal files and the WUID appended:

```
NrmFiles             := dataset('~temp::allfilelist::normal', FsLogicalFileInfoRecord, THOR);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| retrieve the workunit ID for each filenme
| The CATCH function executes the action (set the value returned to 'NOTFND') if the 
| GetLogicalFileAttribute expression fails for any reason
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
FN_Retrieve_WUID(string pFname) := FUNCTION
   RETURN CATCH(STD.File.GetLogicalFileAttribute('~'+TRIM(pFname),'workunit'), 'NOTFND');
END;
dsNormFilesWUID      := PROJECT(  NrmFiles
                                , TRANSFORM(  {FsLogicalFileInfoRecord; string WUID;}
                                            , SELF.WUID := FN_Retrieve_WUID(LEFT.name);
                                              SELF      := LEFT;
                                          ));
output(dsNormFilesWUID, ,'~temp::allfilelist::normal::wuid', compressed, overwrite, expire(30));
```

**PROBLEM**
It was failing to find some files when executing the GetLogicalFileAttribute. That's why I
placed a CATCH() around the statement and it would return a 'NOTFND' instead of failing.
BTW, I had to execute this on an hthor because if I executed on a multi-node THOR, it would fail with a "No access to Dali - this normally means a plugin call is being called from a thorslave".
And wrapping the call in a NOTHOR() would get me a different failure:
"NOTHOR expression 'fn_retrieve_wuid' appears to access a parent dataset - this may cause a dataset not active error"

**QUESTION**
Does the **STD.File.LogicalFileList()** retrieve its information from the DFU (Distributed File Utility)?
Does the **STD.File.GetLogicalFileAttribute(logicalfilename, attrname)** retrieve its information from the DALI (based on the file's metadata)?

I believe these statements are correct (based on the type of data returned). That does raise a concern however that the DFU and DALI can get out of sync. I mean on the same BWR / node I can get a list of files and when requesting an attribute based on a file name from that list, that file name might not be found.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your QUESTION is: Both functions get all their metadata results from Dali.

Your statement, "It was failing to find some files when executing the GetLogicalFileAttribute." is the only thing here that troubles me.
I tried writing some test code:

```
IMPORT Std;
NrmFiles := STD.File.LogicalFileList();
NrmFiles;
NewRec := {NrmFiles,STRING20 WUID};
PROJECT(NrmFiles,
        TRANSFORM(NewRec,
                  SELF.WUID := STD.File.GetLogicalFileAttribute('~'+LEFT.name,'workunit'),
                  SELF := LEFT));
```

Because this job is only looking at DFU metadata, there's no reason to ever run it on a Thor, so it should always be run on hThor. My code runs perfectly on my test system, always finding all the logical files I have, whether they were OUTPUT-generated or sprayed.

I suggest that you submit a JIRA ticket (https://track.hpccsystems.com) to report this issue. Before you do that, you should also explore exactly which files are NOT getting picked up by the STD.File.GetLogicalFileAttribute() function to see if you can detect a reason why. It might be possible that the scope checking is preventing access, but probably not very likely.